# MKMapView can't be zoom when its camera heading rotating

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to rotate my map view according to iOS device orientation, I implement it as below

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    self.userDirection = newHeading.trueHeading;
    self.mapView.camera.heading = newHeading.trueHeading;

}
```

then I get a problem that when the camera of mapView is rotating, mapView can't be zoom.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I just had the same issue. Any clue ?

Comment: Yes, i got another way to implement mapView rotating, i will post my solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that `MKMapCamera` is a new class in iOS7, maybe it's unstable.

Finally, I implement mapView rotating in another way:

First, i enlarge the `mapView`

```
#pragma mark - Map View Setup
- (void)setupMapView
{
    // setup size
    double edgeLength = sqrt(pow(screenSize.size.width, 2) + pow(screenSize.size.height, 2));
    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, edgeLength, edgeLength)];
    self.mapView.center = screenCenter;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}
```

Next Step, implement map rotating in CLLocationManager Delegate

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees / 180.0) * (M_PI))
...
...
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
     double radians = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(newHeading.trueHeading);
     [self.mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-radians)];
}
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the method `- (void)setUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated` when you initialize you MKMapView such as :

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading, animated: true)
```

My map did rotate according to the heading with this code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have try this solution as your mention before, but mapView still can'be zoom when it's rotating.

Answer (score 0):

In the MKMapView's delegate, just set a flag to check if the user is trying to zoom:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
  isTouching = YES;
}
```

and turn it off after change:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
  isTouching = NO;
}
```

and change the heading only if not touching:

```
- (void)changeMapHeading:(CLLocationDirection)heading
{
  if (!isTouching)
  {
    targetMapView.camera.heading = heading;
  }
}
```

btw, you may also want to reduce the update frequency of heading from LocationManager:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
  NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
  NSTimeInterval diff = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastHeadingUpdateTime];
  if (diff > 0.1)
  {
    lastHeadingUpdateTime = now;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationTrackingHeadingUpdated object:newHeading];
  }
}
```